# Set a contract containing deferred transaction from front-end

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs, deferred-transactions

I am trying to figure out the way to set contract which has deferred transactions at run time from front-end.

Is it even doable?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: from front-end meaning from a user-facing interface? you can just process the user input and trigger a transaction to a contract that has an action which handles deferred transactions

Comment: Yes, from GUI. But if user has to provide the delay for deferred transaction, then don't we have to set a whole new contract or that already deployed contract can handle the dynamic delay? If yes, can you show me some piece of code how can I achieve that.

Comment: can't you just pass the delay as an argument to the function?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I am doing right now. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can send a deferred transaction like you usually would but defining the delay as a function parameter:

```
void send(account_name account, std::string message, uint64_t delay) { 
    eosio::transaction t{};
    t.actions.emplace_back(
        eosio::permission_level(account, N(active)),
        N(othercontract),
        N(othermethod),
        std::make_tuple(contractargs));
    t.delay_sec = delay; // Here you set the delay dynamically
    t.send(N(message), account);
   }
};
```

you'd have to make sure you set the permissions right:

```
$ cleos set account permission account active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"contractaccount","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p account
```

and then you'd call the contract passing the delay at run-time

Comment: In your code above, I am little bit confused about `othercontract`, `othermethod`, `contractargs`._________
`othercontract`: is this the contract name?
`othermethod`: is this the action name defined in cpp file which we have to execute after the given delay?
`contractargs`: are they the arguments to the `othermethod` action name?

Comment: `othercontract` is the contract to which you want to send a deferred transaction, `othermethod` is the name of the action that you want to call, `otherargs` are the arguments passed to that action. I wrote a skeleton for this [somewhere else](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1671/961) if it helps (without dynamic delay)