# How to transfer EOS after a particular delay?

Tags: tokens, transfer, deferred-transactions

I know that there is a concept called deferred transaction but how can I use this concept in transferring the EOS to another account. The scenario is:

> I need to transfer certain amount of coins after a particular delay but as eosio.token account has authority to transfer coins, then how can I make a transfer using my **custom contract** which will be set by my account, to transfer the coins after a delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `transfer` action of `eosio.token` contract with the appropriate arguments after your preferred `delay`:

```
void send(account_name from, account_name to, asset amount, string memo, uint64_t delay) { 
    eosio::transaction t{};
    t.actions.emplace_back(
        eosio::permission_level(from, N(active)), // with `from@active` permission
        N(eosio.token), // You're sending this to `eosio.token`
        N(transfer),   // to their `transfer` action
        std::make_tuple(from, to, amount, memo));  // with the appropriate args
    t.delay_sec = delay; // Set the delay
    t.send(eosio::string_to_name(memo.c_str()), from); // Send the transaction with some ID derived from the memo
   }
};
```

You'll need to set permissions accordingly

```
$ cleos set account permission <sender-account> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<sender-pubkey>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"<contract-account>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <sender-account>
```

Comment: Thanks. Like always, to the rescue ;) . Just a small correction. `t.send(eosio::string_to_name(memo.c_str()), amount);` this should be `t.send(eosio::string_to_name(memo.c_str()), from);`

Comment: but get this problem,  no type named 'transaction' in namespace 'eosio

Comment: @seaify-Freelancer you need to `#include<eosiolib/transaction.hpp>` and use `eosio::transaction` if it's not in your scope. [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/how-can-create-a-deferred-action-which-is-executing-at-specific-interval/1671#1671) is a more complete example code-wise