# Can you create a deferred transaction with cleos?

Tags: cleos, deferred-transactions

I want to create a deferred transaction that can be executed using cleos, is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I tried using cleos push transaction with a modified json file. It got processed by cleos but it never did show up in the blockchain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 19th September:** [v1.3.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.3.0) added a [`--delay-sec`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/5492) flag to `cleos push action` so you can now set a delay for your action from `cleos` directly.

---

I can't see anything in [`programs/cleos/main.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/programs/cleos/main.cpp) that would allow this directly.

The only way that I can think of to do this via `cleos` is to push an action to a contract that allows you to send deferred transactions; example:

```
$ cleos push action account send '["from", "to", "10.0000 EOS", "memo", 50]' -p from
```

And `account::send` can be something as follows (copied from an answer I made [somewhere else](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1905/961)):

```
void account::send(account_name from, account_name to, asset amount, string memo, uint64_t delay) { 
    eosio::transaction t{};
    t.actions.emplace_back(
        eosio::permission_level(from, N(active)), // with `from@active` permission
        N(eosio.token), // You're sending this to `eosio.token`
        N(transfer),   // to their `transfer` action
        std::make_tuple(from, to, amount, memo));  // with the appropriate args
    t.delay_sec = delay; // Set the delay
    t.send(eosio::string_to_name(memo.c_str()), from); // Send the transaction with some ID derived from the memo
   }
};
```

Set permissions

```
 $ cleos set account permission <sender-account> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<sender-pubkey>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"<contract-account>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <sender-account>
```